# Lavavel 5.5 auth:api returns login page using postman

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I have found a handful of these in Google and tried all answers but none are working. I am using postman to try to hit an endpoint on an api im building. I am able to send over an email and password and get a token back. I then apply the token (`Bearer {token}`) and  `Accept:application/json` to the headers with a `GET` and it seems to get into the route group but then redirects me to the `login` page.

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function () { 

    \Log::info('step 1');

    Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {

        \Log::info('step 2');
        Route::get('/products','APIController@getProducts');
        Route::get('/logout','PassportController@logout')->name('logout');

    });

});
```

Through the logs I can see it seems to be getting into the middle area but I am getting a return of a redirect to my login page.

[image]

What would be causing this?

Comment: Do you have those defined in `routes/web.php` or `routes/api.php`?

Comment: that is from my routes/api.php

Comment: Check your `storage/logs/laravel.log` file to see if there is any useful error message

Comment: this is whats coming up:local.INFO: step 1
local.INFO: step 2

Comment: I redid the login token and not it goes to 404 not login. I changed my api route to Route::get('/v1/products', 'ApiController@getProducts')->middleware('auth:api'); and it worked. Why isnt the grouping working though?

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/v1'], function () { 

\Log::info('step 1');

Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {

    \Log::info('step 2');
    Route::get('/products','APIController@getProducts');
    Route::get('/logout','PassportController@logout')->name('logout');

});
```

});